# Parameterized field name

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I was thinking if this will work:

```
Dim query As String = "UPDATE tblPiglets SET @to=@todate, CurrentLocation=@to" & _
        " WHERE Week=@week AND SowOrder=@so AND PigletNumber=@pig"
```

But I caught `Cannot update @to field` lol
The `@to` is a variable in which I thought would work the same its value though its worth a try. Its value is dependent on a user input, so, is there any other way to do that?
Or this? (*not sure if this will work though*):

```
Dim to As String = "foo"
Dim query As String = "UPDATE tblPiglets SET " & to & "=@todate, CurrentLocation=@to" & _
        " WHERE Week=@week AND SowOrder=@so AND PigletNumber=@pig"
```

Comment: Typically, when I'm not sure whether something will work, I try it. If your whole query is as you've shown above, you will also get similar errors for todate, week, so and pig. They can be resolved in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always preferable to use parameters to insert user input into SQL code but parameters can only be used for values, not identifiers.  Think of SQL parameters the same as parameters in a VB method.  You can't use a method parameter to specify a property or method to use and you can't use a SQL parameter to specify a column or table.

You have no choice but to use string concatenation but doing so opens you up to SQL injection, so make absolutely sure that the user cannot insert arbitrary SQL code.  If it's a column name then they should have to select it from a list that you have retrieved from the database itself, so that you are guaranteed that it's a valid column.

Answer (score 0):

I have used option 2 to make it work.

```
Dim to As String = "foo"
Dim query As String = "UPDATE tblPiglets SET " & to & "=@todate, CurrentLocation=@to" & _
    " WHERE Week=@week AND SowOrder=@so AND PigletNumber=@pig"
```

But it would be nicer if I can get the same result if I will be using the first option. thanks

Comment: Each answer should be a direct answer to the original question.  If you have a comment to make about an answer or someone else's comment then add a comment, not an answer.